# Multiple iframe src

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

**Hello all,**

I have multiple iframes in my page, each has different src.
Once i load the page, all of them loaded with the same src, not different as i specified for each.

```
<html><body>
<iframe id="1" name="iframe1" src="page.php?id=1"></iframe>
<iframe id="2" name="iframe2" src="page.php?id=2"></iframe>
<iframe id="3" name="iframe3" src="page.php?id=3"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Where is the problem ? how can i solve it ?!!

Comment: example of the problem: <iframe id="1" name="iframe1" src="page.php?id=1"></iframe>
<iframe id="2" name="iframe2" src="page.php?id=1"></iframe>
<iframe id="3" name="iframe3" src="page.php?id=1"></iframe> ............ Same page ID as you see.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `id`s can't be single numbers. (`<iframe id="1"`)

Answer (score 0):

With CSS2, you can't have a single number as a CSS ID as [it cannot start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/PR-CSS2-19980324/syndata.html#q4) - I would change it to the following to ensure backwards compatibility:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="page.php?id=1"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" name="iframe2" src="page.php?id=2"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe3" name="iframe3" src="page.php?id=3"></iframe>
```

Also check if the actual source pages `page.php?id=1` `page.php?id=2` `page.php?id=3` are in fact rendering different pages by visiting the URL through your developer toolbar.

Comment: ok, the iframe ids is not only digits, its mixed from words and digits. But till now, i don't know where the problem is !!